# pass arguments to a command in bash

Tags: bash, clang-format

I'm trying to pass `arg` to `clang-format`:

```
arg="-style=\"{BreakBeforeBraces: Attach}\""
clang-format -i $arg 'myfile.h'
```

but got the following error:

```
No such file or directory
Invalid value for -style
```

However, if I simply run the command like below:

```
clang-format -i -style="{BreakBeforeBraces: Attach}" 'myfile.h'
```

It works perfectly fine.

Comment: Use shell array or function for this

Comment: @anubhava thanks. can you elaborate a bit more about why and how to use shell array / functions to fix the issue please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell removes the double quotes when you run the command directly, so no need to quote them in the variable value.

You need to doublequote the variable, though, to keep its content one word:

```
arg='-style={BreakBeforeBraces: Attach}'
clang-format -i "$arg" myfile.h
```

If the number of the arguments is not fixed (including a possible 0), use an array:

```
args=('-style={BreakBeforeBraces: Attach}')
clang-format -i "${args[@]}" myfile.h
```

Comment: It seems like if arg is an empty string (in case I don't need additional styles, e.g. arg="", then use it this way will give me an error "No such file or directory".

Comment: If the number of arguments is not fixed, use an array.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create a function like this:

```sh
cfmt() {
   clang-format -i "$@"
}
```

Then use it as:

```
cfmt -style="{BreakBeforeBraces: Attach}" myfile.h
```

---

Other safe way is to store arguments in a shell array:

```sh
arg=('-i' '-style="{BreakBeforeBraces: Attach}"')

# use it as
clang-format "${arg[@]}" 'myfile.h'
```

Comment: My intention is to pass the style to clang-format because this can be a different style in different situation. I have no problem to wrap them in a function.

Comment: Sure, check my updated answer